# Structure of data : CPT + terms

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

good morning,

It’s not  technical question about query or something else but about sructure of data.
My current organisation doesn’t satisfy me, I’would need some advices please.
The site speaks about artists, cultural news (POST), books (CPT) or Workshop (CPT), .
My problem concerns the way of treating the « artist » data.

I create a taxonomie «  artist_name ».
Ok.
So, I can connect the posts (books, posts…) which have relation with this artist.

But…

I would like too artists to be associated with categories, or disciplines (like "panting", "photography"… = custom taxonomies)
For exemple  :

- Sophie Calle > photography, humour, intimate life
- Herb Lubalin > graphic design, typography…

So, stop me if I’m wrong, but the only solution is to create (custom) post « artist_portrait » and then check the good categories and taxonomies.
In conclusion I have a custom post *'Portrait of Sophie Calle'*

- Category : intimate life etc…
- Tax Discipline : photography
- Tax artist_name : *calle_sophie*

Don’t you find this « tricky » ? Or redundant (term sophie_calle + CPT Sophie Calle) ?

Last question (promised…) : is it better, for performance, to add some informations  (like year of bearth/death) INSIDE the Custom Post (throughout the custom field), or INSIDE the term (throught Advanced Custom Fields) ?

Sorry for my long and laborious message, **thanks for your time and help !**

Comment: Perhaps, the solution is to join taxonomy term : I saw this article but it's not clear for me : 
http://strangework.com/2014/08/08/understanding-wordpress-taxonomy-table-relationships/"

Comment: I've just read this : "Taxonomies are a relationship between posts, there is no way to create a defined, persistent relationship between two taxonomies." in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30717975/creating-a-relationship-between-two-wordpress-taxonomies. 
Very surprised : is it true ?